# How to get breadcrumbs working on multi-lingual Joomla 3?

Tags: joomla

I have two menus: English and Swedish. When I set English homepage to language `All` then the `Language Switcher` module is not displaying UK flag, only Swedish appears. In this case breadcrumbs works.

If I set English homepage to language `English (UK)` then Language Switcher module shows both flags BUT breadcrumbs is not working correctly? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make a joomla multilingual site work properly you have to set up 3 menus with one default homepage to each.

The first one will be language independent (homepage language "All").

The second menu will be for first language (homepage language "English").

The third one for second language (homepage language "Swedish").

The default language would be set from `Extensions -> Language Manager`