# Webpage doesn't open after multi language configuration

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm a new Joomla user, and i'm configuring my website, to set a multi language switcher. After fallow all of the steps in this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cm114SqvUuc) i opened the webpage, and it always shows me this error on the pic:

[image: Error Printscreen]

I tried to check all of the steps, and i think that everything's right.

Edited:
I changed to max level error reporting, and i got these errors:

> Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.internal_encoding is deprecated in >/home/sbmobili/public_html/libraries/joomla/string/string.php on line 27
>
> Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.input_encoding is deprecated in >/home/sbmobili/public_html/libraries/joomla/string/string.php on line 28
>
> Deprecated: iconv_set_encoding(): Use of iconv.output_encoding is deprecated in >/home/sbmobili/public_html/libraries/joomla/string/string.php on line 29

Edited (2):
If i remove the "www" in the URL, the website opens, but without any multi language reference.

Someone knows how to solve?

Big thank's.

Comment: There are a number of answers at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=language that may help you out.

Comment: @GDP I tried to find a similar situation, but i didn't find anything. Btw, thank's for the advice.

Comment: Please check my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398979/3834042

Comment: @emmanuel i have these three menus as you said in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this problem was easily fixed . I just cleaned the browser cache and it worked.